# How to check in javascript that how much div settle as rows in wrapper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The source is here http://jsfiddle.net/4fV3k/

I have a function `SetGridBorder` which take style of border like `1px solid red` and selector of wrapper like `box-wrapper`.

As my example code 4 rows is lived in a row so their is 4 cols and 4 rows. How I can determine it in JavaScript. I want to set the border in this rules.

1. the 2 and 3 in first row have missing left and right border (so this is not duplicate border).
2. 2nd and third column (middles rows) have missing top and bottom border so no duplicate border for here also.

How I can do it in JavaScript? Do someone have suggestion for how to do it better?

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    var box_wrapper = $(".box-box-wrapper", ".box");   
    SetGridBorder(4,4)
});

function SetGridBorder(style,selector) {

}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get how many rows and columns by divide wrapper width and height to box width and height. In your example wrapper height was zero, so i added `overflow:auto;` to `body .box-wrapper` class. Updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/4fV3k/7/

```
function getRows() {
    var wrapperWidth = $(".box-wrapper").width();
    var boxWidth = $(".box-wrapper > div").width();
    return Math.floor(wrapperWidth / boxWidth);
}

function getColumns() {
    var wrapperHeight = $(".box-wrapper").height();
    var boxHeight = $(".box-wrapper > div").height();
    return Math.floor(wrapperHeight / boxHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI.

```
 body .box {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
    border:solid 1px #555;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each($(".box"),function(i,n){
        if((i+1)%4!=0){
            $(n).css({'border-right':'none'})        
        }
        if((i+1)>4){
           $(n).css({'border-top':'none'})        
        }
    });
});
```